# sheet.appendrow in adwords scripts is appending too many lines

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I'm trying to add rows to a google spreadsheet through an adwords script which runs daily.

Some of the code so far is:

```js
var report_iter = AdWordsApp.report(
  'SELECT ' + columns_str +
  'FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
  'DURING YESTERDAY', { apiVersion: 'v201302' }
).rows();

while(report_iter.hasNext()) {
  var row = report_iter.next();
  var row_array = [""]; // This is deliberate to include an empty cell in column A in the spreadsheet.
  for(var i in columns) {
    row_array.push(row[columns[i]]); 
  }
  sheet.appendRow(row_array); // I think this line might be the problem
}
```

It is working properly, however, it has some unwanted outcomes as well. What I want to stop is every time I append a row to the bottom of the spreadsheet, it also appends 50 other rows of blank cells. Then, the next time I append a row, it appends it to the bottom of the spreadsheet, 50 rows after the one before... Is there any way to stop this. I had a look at using feed lists but I don't know how to do that or if you can with adwords scripts.

The only other thing I was thinking was to insert a new row to the bottom every time, find the row number, then insert data based on the row number.

What I had was working perfectly 3 days ago, but now it has just stopped.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: tag as google-app-script?

Comment: Have you checked the "View > Execution Transcript" to see if you're calling the `appendRow` multiple times? If that's not it, please post the whole code so we can try to reproduce it (including global variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you should not use appendRow. It would be much faster and efficient if you write all the rows at once using getRange setValues and using sheet.getLastRow to calculate the starting row.

2) if you do use appendRow, it will append to the last non-empty row, so it should work ok and shouldnt be writting past the blank rows that are autoinserted.  However maybe you have something like an arrayformula or something else operating on an entire column that is writting in those empty rows at the bottom. Even if it writes blank values those rows wont be considered empty so the next appendRow will write below them.

Comment: Perfect. Point 2 was the problem. I did it using 1! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The something is probably one of the calls setting the array to 30 rows, then only emptying the array, but not creating a new resized one.

But #1 is the way to go...